# NSDataDetector crashes when url contains "%20"

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, nsdatadetector

Using Swift 4, I am trying to detect urls within strings. I am currently using this code:

```
let urlLink : String = "https://skift.com/2017/11/27/8-financial-themes-shaping-the-hotel-industry-in-2018-and-beyond/?utm_campaign=Early%20Time%20Zone%20-%20Skift%20Daily%20Newsletter&utm_source=hs_email&utm_medium=email&utm_content=58793637&_hsenc=p2ANqtz-8cG4tZKNEv7E1FRrVn-T-qwKRpJKx8JQBAgF7priRL78ToAX49w4e1R2sdCxSI9lik4NXXkW241XSN3UkVxVrjVjRu7x0N8i-txn8F0Jxnhgej3OI&_hsmi=58793637"
let detector = try! NSDataDetector(types: NSTextCheckingResult.CheckingType.link.rawValue)
let matches = detector.matches(in: urlLink, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: urlLink.count))
```

As you can see, my string is already formatted to replace the spaces with **"%20"**.

The issue is that my code is crashing on the last line. Is there a better way to format my string?

I found a workaround by replacing all **"%20"** by **""**, which is working fine, but I am sure there is a better way to handle it.

Comment: Your code compiles and runs fine. You should handle the error rather than to hazard a crash.

Comment: Note that you should use urlLink.utf16.count instead of urlLink.count

Answer (score 0):

check this one

```
let detector = try! NSDataDetector(types: NSTextCheckingResult.CheckingType.link.rawValue)
                        let matches = detector.matches(in: input!, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, (input?.characters.count)!))
                        var url = String()
                        for match in matches

                        {
                            url = (input! as NSString).substring(with: match.range)

                        }
```